# Earth sized object with negative mass superimposed 1:1 on Earth. What happens to its orbit?

Tags: science-fiction, gravity

Assume the superpower to instantly conjure a 1:1 Earth sized object with negative mass exactly equivalent to earth size and mass but negative, superimposed upon Earth.

Also, please keep in mind objects with positive mass and negative mass do not interact with each other except for the gravitational forces they exert on each other. Otherwise, they simply pass through each other like ghost objects in the world.

What happens to the planet Earth in orbit? Ignore effects on living things but feel free to address what will happen at the surface.

Particularly interested in what happens to the orbits of the earth and its natural satellite, the moon. But optionally, feel free to address what happens to the solar system as a whole and any effects this might have on the other planets in the system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where exactly does this negative mass earth-like object get conjured?

Comment: @MontyWild it's conjured superimposed 1:1 over Earth.

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that it would be essentially different from just eliminating Earth using a similar conjuration? (Excluding the obvious: there is something you can see and collide with.)

Comment: @JaniMiettinen ah, I was under the perception that the Earth would remain intact as objects with negative mass would not interact with objects with positive mass. They would simply pass through each other in the world. (thanks for pointing that out, will add that context to the question description)

Answer (score 4):

[Negative mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) behaves differently to normal, positive mass.  Positive mass attracts other masses, while negative mass repels other masses.

If the positive mass earth (Earth+) and the superimposed negative mass earth (Earth-) do not physically interact save for their gravitic influence, Earth+ is still doomed, since Earth+ and Earth- are within each-others [Roche limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit).

At planetary scales, planets can be considered to behave like a fluid.  Since the negative mass Earth- will be repelled from itself and will also repel positive masses with forces equivalent to up to 2g, both Earth+ and Earth- are likely to quickly break up.  Positive masses will be attracted to the negative masses as they depart from the vicinity of Earth+, and they will, in effect, pull Earth+ apart.  The atmosphere will be stripped off and the seas will flow into the sky as the 'phantom' negative matter flees the concentration of matter.  Anything not fixed to the ground will follow, including people, before the earth's crust and mantle begins to disintegrate as it tries to follow the pieces of the disintegrating Earth-.

As a positive/negative mass pair effectively forms a [diametrical drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_propulsion), the fragments of Earth+/Earth- will accelerate away from the former location of Earth+, making it effectively impossible for Earth+ to re-coalesce.  The solid chunks of Earth+/Earth- may be quite large on a human scale, but they will be small enough that their cohesiveness is greater than the gravitic forces trying to break them apart.  The gravitic forces associated with them may be relatively small, so the positive/negative mass pairs won't accelerate all that quickly... but they *will* accelerate.

While the atmosphere, waters and unattached mass will depart relatively quickly, within a few minutes, Earth- will also be repelled from the sun as it disintegrates.  Since Earth- and Earth+ contribute more to the local gravitic environment, the Earth+/- pair will also accelerate away from the sun as they disintegrate under their internal and mutual influence.

If Earth+/- passes near any other planet, it may cause some slight interaction, but this is quite improbable given the size of space and the relative size of the outer planets.

Since the attraction between the Earth and the Moon would effectively become zero, the Moon would travel away from Earth while continuing in orbit around the Sun as if the Earth didn't exist.  Depending upon the relative positions of Sun, Earth+/- and Moon when Earth- appears, it may be possible for a collision between Earth+/-  and the Moon to occur.

Comment: Tidal forces are a result of the gravitational gradient (difference in gravitational pull) across an object. The part of the satellite closer to the primary experiences a stronger pull than the part farther away. 

Here, in this case, the tidal forces are equal and opposite to each other, both pulling in and repelling out along the same gradient, effectively cancelling each out. Hence, the Roche limit won't apply here.

Comment: @Pre-alpha Roche limit applies in the sense of gravitic forces overcoming cohesive forces, not necessarily due to any gravitic gradient.

Comment: That's true, nevertheless, I highly doubt that it will lead to complete disintegration. It's more likely that there is some sort of oscillation throughout the core, mantle, and crust effectively causing a very unstable surface with constant earthquakes, volcanic eruptions and the like as the planet continuously goes through the push and pull of both the negative and positive masses. Still unsure about the orbital implications though.

Comment: Earth- is going to be repelled from itself and Earth+.  It *is* going to disintegrate, and pull pieces of Earth+ along with it, and the remains will be pulled away, probably away from the sun.  Some of the pieces could be quite big, though, where cohesiveness is greater than the gravitic forces.

Comment: Right, when the positive and negative earths drift slowly apart, won't the tidal forces still cancel each other out as the distance between the two objects slowly increases? The push and pull will also slowly decrease. Maybe planet-wide fissures and cracks happen due to the push and pull stresses, but as the negative earth drifts away, the positive earth slowly heals under its own gravitational forces.

Comment: Chunks of Earth+/- will accelerate away from the site of the conjunction.  Earth- matter will spread out, and pull Earth+ in different directions.  When gravitic forces are less than cohesive forces, the chunks will stop breaking apart... more or less.

Answer (score 1):

> objects with positive mass and negative mass do not interact with each other except for the gravitational forces they exert on each other

Being superimposed, both bodies would be inside the Roche limit of the other one. This would mean that the tidal forces. This would result in both bodies starting to break off under tidal forces and disgregate into chunks which would start going around subjected to attractive and repulsive forces of the other chunks surrounding them.

Meanwhile, under influence of the Sun gravity, the center of mass of the nEarth would start being pushed further away than Earth, meaning that there might be hope for some of the fragments of Earth to coalesce back into a larger body, which of course would be a ball of molten rock.

Comment: Tidal forces are a result of the gravitational gradient (difference in gravitational pull) across an object. The part of the satellite closer to the primary experiences a stronger pull than the part farther away. 

Here, in this case, the tidal forces are equal and opposite to each other, both pulling in and repelling out along the same gradient, effectively cancelling each out. Hence, the Roche limit won't apply here.

Comment: @Pre-alpha wrong. Because the nEarth is repelled by the Sun, so from moment 0 it will start moving away, thus creating tidal forces.

Comment: Right, when the positive and negative earths drift slowly apart, won't the tidal forces still cancel each other out as the distance between the two objects slowly increases? The push and pull will also slowly decrease. Maybe planet-wide fissures and cracks happen due to the push and pull stresses, but as the negative earth drifts away, the positive earth slowly heals under its own gravitational forces.